# Synthesis of Pt(II) complex using trans effect

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, cis-trans-isomerism, stereoselectivity

> By making use of the *trans*-effect in platinum(II) complexes, show efficient routes for the synthesis of all the possible isomers of $\ce{[PtCl(NH3)2(py)]+}$ (where $\ce{py}$ = pyridine) from the starting material $\ce{K2PtCl4}$.

So far, I've had problems with trying to substitute ammonia and py in the right places. Since $\ce{Cl-}$ is higher on the trans effect list than the two ligands I want to substitute with, I found that it's just not possible to do that.

Comment: So, exactly what possible routes have you contemplated?